# Маршрутизировать трафик одного tun-интерфейса через другой tun. Double VPN

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables, vpn, openvpn

На сервере есть 3 сетевых интерфейса:

- `eth0` - интернет
- `tun1` - openvpn-сервер(10.8.1.1/24)
- `tun2s1` - интерфейс tun2socks, подключенный через `eth0`(10.9.1.1/24)

Мне нужно чтобы трафик с tun1 ходил через tun2s1.

Примерная схема: `Client -> tun1 -> tun2s1 -> eth0`

Если выполнить команду `curl --interface tun2s1 http://site.com`, то запрос совершается верно, то есть `tun2s1` подключен корректно. Проблема в подключении `tun1` и `tun2s1` интерфейсов.

Я попробовал создать новую таблицу маршрутизации и направлять через нее, но это тоже пока не сработало

С помощью tcpdump мониторю оба tun-интерфейса, вижу как на tun1 ходят пакеты 10.8.1.2 > 1.1.1.1, а на tun2s1 - 1.1.1.1 > 10.8.1.2. Но на клиенте vpn все равно не проходит пинг

Команды:

```
ip route add 10.9.1.0/32 dev tun2s1 src 10.9.1.1 table admin
ip route add default via 10.9.1.1 dev tun2s1 table admin
ip rule add to 10.8.1.0/24 table admin
ip rule add from 10.8.1.0/24 table admin
```

Настройки:

```
/ip_forward=1
*/rp_filter=0
*/accept_local=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
# Включаем ip forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Маскируем трафик
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.1/24 -o tun2s1 -j MASQUERADE

# Добавляем новую таблицу маршрутизации
echo "100  admin" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Добавляем интерфейс в новую таблицу
ip route add 10.9.1.0/32 dev tun2s1 src 10.9.1.1 table admin

# Объявляем интерфейсом по-умолчанию
ip route add default via 10.9.1.1 dev tun2s1 table admin

# Создаем правило маршрутизации для tun1, направляющее трафик с tun1 в таблицу admin 
ip rule add from 10.8.1.0/24 table admin 

# Чистим кэш ip route для обновления правил
ip route flush cache

# Отключаем фильтр обратного пути для всех интерфейсов*
for i in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do
  echo 0 > $i 
done

# Включаем пакеты с локальных источников для всех интерфейсов*
for i in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_local ; do
  echo 1 > $i 
done
```

*Думаю можно и не для всех, но это для меня сработало и уже нет времени на эту задачу. Если вы знаете как лучше - напишите, я отредактирую ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос в том с каким IP должны вылетают в eth0 пакеты пришедшие с tun0.

Вам надо прописать строчку (пишу по памяти, могу ошибиться) :

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.9.1.1
```

Возможно вместо 10.9.1.1 нужно будет прописать внешний IP туннеля tun2s1, не IP той стороны тоннеля а внешний IP вашей стороны.

Ну и проверить что разрешен форвардинг в  `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`